# Is it possible to use Whatsapp via a browser (web.whatsapp.com) to make Whatsapp video calls?

Tags: whatsapp

Is it possible to use Whatsapp via a browser (web.whatsapp.com) or via the Whatsapp Desktop app to make Whatsapp video calls ?

Im aware I can use the messaging feature through the above website / desktop but couldn’t see if it was possible to make video calls.

Below are some screenshots from Whatsapp Desktop for OSX.

[image: screenshot of whatsapp OSX]

[image: screenshot of whatsapp OSX]

Comment: Yes if paired with a phone #

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 where can this be done from, i couldnt find the option to make a video call

Comment: Click on a contact chat and see if in the top-right corner if it's there.